# define global params in android

Tags: android, global-variables

want to define some global const parameters (arrs , int etc..) in one java file so the all activity can reach them and use them.
 I tried to define them globaly in some activity and do import to this activity but it isn't work.

In level_1_general:

```
    public int NUMBER_OF_WORDS=50;
```

The import:

```
import com.example.freeenglish.Level1_general;
```

What is the right way to do that?

Comment: try storing in preferences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a common pattern is to create a `Costants` class with a private constructor in which you put every costants your app need. eg

```
public class Costants {

  public static final int NUMBER_OF_WORDS=50;
  private Costants() {}
}
```

then you are able to access your variable with

```
Costants.NUMBER_OF_WORDS
```

Comment: where do I call the constructor?

Comment: you do not need to instatiate the class. All the static filed can be access through the name of the class,

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class that `extends Application` so the whole application can import and use it's methods and consts.

Comment: like that:
  public class Level1_general extends Application  {
  
 public int NUMBER_OF_WORDS=50;
 }?

Comment: Yes. And if it really is a constant, make it static. `public static int NUMBER_OF_WORDS=50;`

Comment: You really don't need an `Application` subclass just to get some static fields. Any class can have static fields.

Comment: @DanHulme you are right. Although, for better understaing on coding later on, declaring common application constants, methods and etc. on a class that exenteds Application makes coding better. AND you can use `getApplicationContext()` for a reference to this class. AFAIK.

Comment: Better in what way? I confess I am unable to see any benefits. The [documentation for `Application`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) specifically recommends against extending `Application` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You may also create a java class in your application package where you can declare and define all your static and final variable after that you can access all static variable using class name i.e.

```
public class StaticData {

public static final int NUMBER_OF_WORDS;
      //declarer rest of static variable.....

static{

    //give all that variables a default value....  

    NUMBER_OF_WORDS=50;
}}
```